# I could not find why "Using organization 1" appear in the attached log. In the bash shell script, which command line make it appear?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

```
    1) run this script
        @ubuntu:~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network$ 
       ./network.sh deployCC

    2) I got bellow logs

    ===================== Chaincode is packaged on peer0.org1 ===================== 

    Installing chaincode on peer0.org1...
    Using organization 1  ------->>> this is my concern. why this log appear?
    ++ peer lifecycle chaincode install fabcar.tar.gz
    ++ res=0
    ++ set +x
    2020-05-08 20:28:23.265 PDT [cli.lifecycle.chaincode] submitInstallProposal -> INFO 001 Installed remotely: response: 
    2020-05-08 20:28:23.272 PDT [cli.lifecycle.chaincode] submitInstallProposal -> INFO 002 Chaincode code package identifier: fabcar_1:f560ce2c5aaa05939209c9ba253e53ca2738e3b86f67cf7ba0ed37f74e7df74e
    ===================== Chaincode is installed on peer0.org1 ===================== 

    Install chaincode on peer0.org2...
    Using organization 2  ------->>> this is my concern. why this log appear?
    ++ peer lifecycle chaincode install fabcar.tar.gz
    ++ res=0
    ++ set +x

    ===================== Chaincode is installed on peer0.org2 =====================
```

Comment: Please provide a link to a bash script or a script itself, since otherwise the problem would not be reproducible. Also consider adding a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

That message is telling you that you are installing your chaincode on the peers of both organization 1 and organization 2.

peer0.org1----chaincode is installing on organization1 peer that is peer0

peer0.org2----chaincode is installing on organization2 peer that is peer0

Answer (score 0):

The overall flow to deploy chaincode is 4 steps:

1. Package the chaincode
2. Install it on your org peers
3. Approve the chaincode definition for your organization, and
4. Commit the chaincode definition to your channel.

In this case you are at Step 2, install the chaincode package.

Starting in deployCC.sh you have

```
# installChaincode PEER ORG
installChaincode() {
  ORG=$1
  setGlobals $ORG
```

setGlobals() is in envVar.sh where you have

```
# Set environment variables for the peer org
setGlobals() {
  local USING_ORG=""
  if [ -z "$OVERRIDE_ORG" ]; then
    USING_ORG=$1
  else
    USING_ORG="${OVERRIDE_ORG}"  
  fi
  echo "Using organization ${USING_ORG}"
```

That last echo is where the line:

```
Using organization 1
```

is printed from.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fully understand it cause your kind comments!